# It takes a lot of time for flutter app loading

Tags: flutter, firebase

[image: point 1]
[image: point 2]

It takes a lot of time app loading for second app starting not first app start.
Two points have consumed long time ( almost 1 min )

[+29806 ms] DevFS: Creating new filesystem on the device (null)

```
type here
```

[+29848 ms] I/FLTFireMsgService( 7408): FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService started!

my stack is like following.

```
firebase_core: ^2.3.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.10
firebase_messaging: ^14.1.2

flutter local notification : 12.0.4
```

[image: Environment]

if you have any solution, would you like to share the solution for this ?

Comment: Same problem! 
I tried to roll back to Flutter 3.3.10
No results

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with updating Firebase_auth and Firebase_core to the latest version!